# How to rectify model.json having more columns than outputted CSV file

Tags: pyspark, dynamics-crm, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, common-data-service

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a CSV file located in an Azure Data Lake (gen2) in the CDM format. The file definition is located in a model.json file at the top level; the file describes every entity in the data lake. This data is outputted by [Microsoft's automatic CDS replication to Azure Data Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/export-to-data-lake).

My goal is to read this file and do some processing in Azure Databricks. I can successfully read the model.json file and extract the columns names for each entity, but I run into certain CSV files that have less columns than is described in the model.json file, and as you can imagine trying to apply these columns names to the non-headered CSV files will result in an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn&#39;t match.
```

Below are some code snippets describing the transformation process. Any help is appreciated. If there is an easier way to process the data in the CSV files then I am also interested in hearing this.

Loading the model.json file

```
model = spark.read.json(base_path + "model.json", multiLine=True)
entities = model.select(explode(model["entities"]).alias("entity"))
entity_info = entities.select("entity.name", "entity.attributes", "entity.partitions")
```

Extracting the column names and file paths from the JSON file

```
entity_metadata = (
  filtered_entity_info.withColumn("attributes", explode("attributes"))
  .select("name", "partitions", col("attributes")["name"].alias("column_name"))
)

entity_metadata = (
  entity_metadata.groupBy("name", "partitions")
  .agg(collect_list("column_name").alias("columns"))
  .select("*")
)

entity_metadata = (
  entity_metadata.withColumn("partitions", explode("partitions"))
  .select("name", col("partitions")["location"].alias("filePath"), "columns")
)
```

Loading the file, applying the column names in an attempt to create a DF

```
def build_file_url(file_url):
  url = file_url.split(blob_container_name + "/")[1]
  return base_path + url
  
  
def populate_entity_df(tableName, url, column_names):
  file_path = build_file_url(url)
  df = (
    spark.read.option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ',')
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .csv(file_path)
  )
  return df.toDF(*column_names)

array_of_metadatas = entity_metadata.collect()

opportunity_metadata = next(x for x in array_of_metadatas if x.name == "opportunity")

opportunity_df = populate_entity_df(opportunity_metadata.name, opportunity_metadata.filePath, opportunity_metadata.columns)
```

And, if interested, here is an example of the model.json file.

```json
{
    "name": "cdm",
    "description": "cdm",
    "version": "1.0",
    "entities": [
        {
            "$type": "LocalEntity",
            "name": "account",
            "description": "account",
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "name": "Athena:PartitionGranularity",
                    "value": "Year"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Athena:InitialSyncState",
                    "value": "Completed"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Athena:InitialSyncDataCompletedTime",
                    "value": "9/1/2020 3:43:50 PM"
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "Id",
                    "dataType": "guid"
                },
                {
                    "name": "SinkCreatedOn",
                    "dataType": "dateTime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "SinkModifiedOn",
                    "dataType": "dateTime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "statecode",
                    "dataType": "int64"
                },
                {
                    "name": "statuscode",
                    "dataType": "int64"
                },
                ...
            ],
            "partitions": [
                {
                    "name": "2020",
                    "location": "https://<storage account>.dfs.core.windows.net:443/<blob container>/opportunity/Snapshot/2020_1602009522.csv",
                    "fileFormatSettings": {
                        "$type": "CsvFormatSettings",
                        "columnHeaders": false,
                        "delimiter": ",",
                        "quoteStyle": "QuoteStyle.Csv",
                        "csvStyle": "CsvStyle.QuoteAlways",
                        "encoding": "UTF-8"
                    },
                    "annotations": [
                        {
                            "name": "Athena:PartitionYear",
                            "value": "2020"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its a classic issue of the outputted CSV file not having commas for every columns. I didn't spot this because Dynamics 365 entities have hundreds of columns and seeing 387 commas instead of 378 didn't quite register when looking at the files.

```
jim,12,
bob,13,programmer,texas,houston
jane,88,director,alaska
```

PySpark, when using the .csv api, only uses the first row's number of columns and drops any extra columns from future rows.

To get around this I use the list of column names to generate a schema at runtime.

```py
def get_schema(cols):
  arr = []
  for col in cols:
    arr.append(StructField(col, StringType(), True))
  return StructType(arr)
```

I'm just using StringType for now, but in the future it seems easy enough to also pull in the data type from the entity definitions and create a mapping.

To tie it all together, here is how the schema is applied:

```py
df = (
  spark.read.option("header", "false")
    .schema(schema)
    .option("delimiter", ',')
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .csv(file_path)
)
```